# How to Encode categorical data into labels for training and testing

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The training dataset has object columns called shops and others. Now for the machine learning model I converted the columns into labels for training purposes. Using the code below

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
X = df_all_4.copy()
y = df_all_4.item_price
X = X.drop(['item_price','date'], axis=1)
for c in df_all_4.columns[df_all_4.dtypes == 'object']:
    X[c] = X[c].factorize()[0]
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(X,y)
```

Now the testing dataset also has those categorical columns but with the some columns missing including the target column not relevant here I think. But if I again label the training dataset (unordered) the **labels would be different than the one used while training** so the model would not work properly . How to solve this problem and get the same encodings while training and testing

Comment: Use onehotencoder in sklearn

Comment: Can't label them?

Answer (score 0):

The important thing here is you can use LabelEncoder or OneHotEncoder classes present in Sklearn package. which makes this task pretty much simple.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
for c in df_all_4.columns[df_all_4.dtypes == 'object']:
    le = LabelEncoder()
    X[c] = le.fit_transform(X[c])
    test[c] = le.transform(test[c])
```

That's it you have encoded the labels into numbers for both train and test data
You can also use OneHotEncoder which does OneHotEncoding to categorical data.

Comment: This wont work because as I have mentioned the testing and training sets are in different order so what is encoded "1" in training data won't be encoded "1' in testing data.

Comment: The order doesn't matter for label encoder once try out and check the results. If the order is important why don't you change the order of columns in the test set similar to train data.